# How to concatenate multiple rows into one based on id in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Actually i have three columns. **ID**, **MedID**, **Name**. With my query i am getting a result look like the below.

```
ID       MedID         Name
 1       101           TestData1
 1       124           TestData2
```

**Query**

```
 select 
    cmd.ID, mm.MedID,mm.Name as Name
 from 
     tbl1 mm
 inner join 
      tbl2 cmd on cmd.medID= mm.MedID
  where
       cmd.ID= 1
```

Actually i am expecting a result like the below

```
 ID          MedID        Name
  1          101,124      TestData1,TestData2
```

So, how can get a result like this, Where i need to do changes in my query?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Nope, its works fine. I just marked the other answer also helpful @GurV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` like this:

```
select id,
    stuff((
            select ',' + cast(MedId as varchar(30))
            from t t1
            where t1.id = t.id
            order by MedID
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') MedID,
    stuff((
            select ',' + Name
            from t t1
            where t1.id = t.id
            order by MedID
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') Name
from t
group by id;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MTMB29231)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID int, MedID  varchar(10), Name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
 (1,       '101' ,          'TestData1'),
 (1,       '124' ,          'TestData2')

SELECT t.ID
      , STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + MedID
                FROM @TABLE 
                WHERE ID = t.ID
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS MedID
      , STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + Name
                FROM @TABLE 
                WHERE ID = t.ID
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Name           
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.ID
```